# PostSharp displays call stack as "Aspect Code" and makes call stack less usable

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, postsharp, callstack

On certain breakpoints in my code, the call stack is displayed as "Aspect Code", and I can't use the call stack window to identify or navigate up the call stack. When does this occur and why?

I uninstalled PostSharp and this went away. Is there a way to stop PostSharp from doing this?

I have the free version of PostSharp. I upgraded from 5. something to 6.0.27 with no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, PostSharp extension in Visual Studio hides the aspect and generated code in the call stack view to make it cleaner and easier to use.

You can disable this feature by opening PostSharp options dialogue and enabling option "Show aspect code in call stack".

If in your case PostSharp hides more than just aspect code, then it would be a bug and we would like to ask you for more information about how to reproduce it.

[image]

Comment: Note that many several bugs in the call stack view are fixed in the 6.1 branch, which is in preview at the time of writing.

Comment: Can you estimate when that will be released so I know when to re-enable this feature? Ballpark

Comment: You can already start using 6.1 preview. If you don't want to deal with the unstable version of the PostSharp compiler, you can install preview of the VS extension only (https://www.postsharp.net/downloads/postsharp-6.1). We cannot promise any specific date for the 6.1 RTM release. Personally, I wouldn't expect it sooner than in two months.